# python equivelant to $(which) in make

Tags: python, python-2.7, makefile

porting a Makefile to dodo.py i want to source the "nikola" on the path rather than directly call it

in Makefile i would do something like

```
NIKOLA = $(which nikola)
```

however i cant seem to find the doit/dodo/python equivelant my current file looks like this

```
import subprocess

Nikola = subprocess.Popen("nikola", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

def task_build():
    return {
        'actions': ['{0} build'.format(Nikola)],
    }
```

however running task_build returns this

```
########################################
Execution aborted.
Task 'build': invalid 'actions' type. got:<subprocess.Popen object at 0x10111f810> <class 'subprocess.Popen'>
(env)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(['which','nikola'])
'/Users/elyase/miniconda/bin/nikola\n'
```

In your case:

```
def task_build():
    return {
        'actions': ['{0} build'.format(Nikola)],
    }

>>> Nikola = subprocess.check_output(['which','nikola']).rstrip()
>>> task_build()
{'actions': ['/Users/elyase/miniconda/bin/nikola build']}
```

Comment: it finds the nikola varible however it runs the argument then command

Comment: sorry I don't get it, can you post your output? Also do you mean the nikola path? what is the nikola variable?